# In Vertica, should you factor out strings into their own logical tables?

Tags: database, rdbms, database-schema, vertica

Suppose your logical table is:

```
CREATE TABLE employee(
  name VARCHAR,
  university VARCHAR
);
```

Now you have only a few universities. Therefore, you *could* factor out the university name:

```
CREATE TABLE employee(
  name VARCHAR,
  university integer references university(university)
);

CREATE TABLE university(
  university identity,
  name varchar
);
```

You have queries of the sort:

```
SELECT employee 
FROM employee as e1 
WHERE EXISTS 
      (SELECT employee 
       FROM employee as e2 
       WHERE e1.name = e2.name AND e1.university <> e2.university)
```

What I'm wondering about is: does the second logical schema, where the name is "factored out", speed up things? Perhaps because there, `e1.university <> e2.university` is a comparison of integers rather than of strings.

Comment: No. The guide said that I should play with the projections only once all data is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question -- but the answer is usually no.  The encoding that the product does will generally shrink the column enough that it is faster than the join that would have to occur.